# Potential problem with the C++ compiler when installing pysph

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to install pysph. I tried with MSVC 2017 and with MSVC 2022. When I try doing `pip install`, I end up with the following error.

```
 building 'pysph.base.octree' extension
  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD "-IC:\Users\Matthew Scholar\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-8kmg9l2e\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include" "-Ic:\users\matthew scholar\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\include" "-Ic:\users\matthew scholar\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\Include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\cppwinrt" /EHsc /Tppysph/base/octree.cpp /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-38\Release\pysph/base/octree.obj /openmp
  octree.cpp

  c:\users\matthew scholar\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-env-8kmg9l2e\overlay\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include\numpy\npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h(14) : Warning Msg: Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with #define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION


  pysph/base/octree.cpp(9616): error C3861: '_Pragma': identifier not found

  pysph/base/octree.cpp(9616): error C2059: syntax error: ';'

  pysph/base/octree.cpp(9634): error C3861: '_Pragma': identifier not found

  pysph/base/octree.cpp(9634): error C2059: syntax error: ';'

  pysph/base/octree.cpp(9769): error C3861: '_Pragma': identifier not found

  pysph/base/octree.cpp(9769): error C2059: syntax error: ';'

  pysph/base/octree.cpp(9787): error C3861: '_Pragma': identifier not found

  pysph/base/octree.cpp(9787): error C2059: syntax error: ';'

  pysph/base/octree.cpp(9927): error C2065: '__pyx_parallel_exc_type': undeclared identifier

  pysph/base/octree.cpp(9929): error C2065: '__pyx_parallel_exc_type': undeclared identifier

  pysph/base/octree.cpp(9930): error C2065: '__pyx_parallel_exc_type': undeclared identifier

  pysph/base/octree.cpp(9930): error C2065: '__pyx_parallel_exc_value': undeclared identifier

  pysph/base/octree.cpp(9930): error C2065: '__pyx_parallel_exc_tb': undeclared identifier

  pysph/base/octree.cpp(9931): error C2065: '__pyx_parallel_filename': undeclared identifier

  pysph/base/octree.cpp(15447): error C3010: '__pyx_L12_error': jump out of OpenMP structured block not allowed
  
  C:\Users\Matthew Scholar\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-8kmg9l2e\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_py.py:202: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning:     Installing 'pysph.base' as data is deprecated, please list it in `packages`.

    check.warn(importable)

  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.16.27023\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2

  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pysph
```

Edit: Fixed by using MSVC 2019 and python 3.8 (with an earlier version of vtk installed for mayavi)

Answer (score 1):

I've never used PySPH but here are some things I would try to rule out:

1. Make sure you are using the correct command, it should be

```html
pip install PySPH
```

This is taken from https://pypi.org/project/PySPH/

2. Try installing from GitHub https://github.com/pypr/pysph

```html
git clone https://bitbucket.org/pysph/pysph.git
```

3. Make sure you have relevant dependencies from the documentation, there is a section specifically for Installing Visual C++ Compiler
   https://pysph.readthedocs.io/en/1.0a1/installation.html#installing-the-dependencies-on-windows

You can check whether or not you have a dependency installed via command prompt

```
<name of dependency> --version
```

4. A possible issue could be tests failing https://github.com/pypr/pysph/actions/workflows/tests.yml
   as of very recently it seems to have been fixed for tests failing on windows. I would recommend installing with git cloning from the latest version